# limsup of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

The series is from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis$ ("Baby Rudin"), p.67.

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+... $$

and Rudin claims that 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

I do not get why this is the case. Can't we pick 
$$\frac{1}{2^3}, \frac{1}{2^6},\frac{1}{2^9}\ldots $$
or higher powers of $\frac{1}{2}$ in which case we get $$\limsup (a_{n_k})^{1/n} = \frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Because each $3^{-3n}$ is $a_{6n}$ but you apply the root test as if $3^{-3n}=a_{9n}$.

Comment: @Did makes a lot of sense. thanks!

Comment: Reatedly, note that, in your post, $$\limsup\ (a_{n_k})^{1/n}$$ is intrinsically faulty, one should consider $$\limsup\ (a_{n_k})^{1/n_k}$$

Comment: Please do not change thoroughly your post after you received comments (especially when, as here, basically the same idea applies).

Comment: @Did I am sorry, I'll make sure not to do that again. I appreciate the feedback

Comment: Yu could first and foremost "make sure" to cancel the unfortunate edit on this very page.

Comment: @Did just did. I corrected it in the first place because it was not correct, namely, $1/3^3 < 1/\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, perhaps easier, to see what's going on, is to observe that:0

$$a_1=\frac12\;,\;a_2=\frac13\;,\;a_3=\frac1{2^2}\;,\;a_4=\frac1{3^2}\;...$$

Clearly, to get the supremum of the above we have to take the odd numbered elements:

$$a_1,\,a_3,\,a_5,\,....\implies \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n-1]{\frac1{2^n}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

Because at index $\;1=2\cdot1-1\;$, we have $\;\frac12\;$ , at index $\;2\cdot2-1=3\;$, we have $\;\frac1{2^2}\;$, ...at index $\;2n-1\;$ , we have $\;\frac1{2^n}\;$ ...

or taking $\;k\;$ to be a general *odd* index, the corresponding element here is $\;\cfrac1{2^{\frac{k+1}2}}\;$ , so again

$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\frac1{2^{\frac k2+\frac12}}}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac1{2^{1/2}\sqrt[k]{\sqrt2}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$